# Connect Spotfire Azure MySQL database

Tags: mysql, azure, spotfire, azure-mysql-database

How do I connect Spotfire to my Azure MySQL database?

I get an error when I try to connect to the normal Microsoft Azure. I'm running Spotfire version 7.7

Comment: if one of these answers solved your problem, please mark it as accepted :) if not, please post the contents of the error.

Comment: I can't accept my own answer :) But that did fix the problem

Answer (score 1):

Here is some information for you to refer.

I am not sure Spotfire supports to connect Azure Database for MySQL(because there is a `Other..` option), refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Besides**, if it supports to connect Azure Database for MySQL, you could refer to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32OOGWFydw0) to do it, it may be similar.

**Note**: You could find *TIBCO Spotfire* says in the link I mentioned:

> The Microsoft SQL Server connector comes with Spotfire and as of Spotfire `7.8` supports use with Azure SQL.

Due to you are running Spotfire version `7.7`, it may also be a reason for your connection error.

Answer (score 0):

Even though it's an Azure MySQL Database, you can use the Oracle connector/driver.

All Sptfire drivers: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-database-drivers

Oracle MySQL driver: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/

Once downloaded, restart Spotfire and then connect using Oracle MySQL with your Azure MySQL credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your public IP address to AZURE firewall?